Complex numbers derivation using Euler's identity.
I am reading this book about complex numbers "An Imaginary Tale" there is one problem which I am stuck at, the author assumes that the reader should be able to show that:
$$ \frac{e^{\frac{i \pi  (2 m+1)}{2 n}}-e^{\frac{i \pi  (2 m+1)}{2 n}} e^{\frac{2 i \pi  (2 m+1) n}{2 n}}}{1-e^{\frac{2 i \pi  (2 m+1)}{2 n}}}=-\frac{i}{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  (2 m+1)}{2 n}\right)}$$
[$n$ and $m$ are integers and $n > m$]
The author gives the hint of remembering the Euler's identity which I can't decide where to use in the above equation.
I have come to this far but now I can't show that the above two sides are actually equal.
If someone could show me how to derive the LHS to make it equal to RHS, probably using Euler's identity?
Thank you.

Hint:$$\exp\frac{2i\pi(2m+1)n}{2n}=\exp[i\pi(2m+1)]=-1.$$

@J.G. Thank you, then it becomes $\frac{2 e^{\frac{i \pi  (2 m+1)}{2 n}}}{\left(1-e^{\frac{i \pi  (2 m+1)}{2 n}}\right) \left(1+e^{\frac{i \pi  (2 m+1)}{2 n}}\right)}$ what next?

You actually don't need to factorize the denominator. Now use $\sin x=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$.

First as @J.G. pointed out, note that $\frac{2 i \pi  (2 m+1) n}{2 n} = i \pi  (2 m+1)$ is always an odd multiple of $i\pi$.  Thus, $e^{\frac{2 i \pi  (2 m+1) n}{2 n}} = -1$, so the expression simplifies to:
$$\frac{e^{\frac{i \pi  (2 m+1)}{2 n}}-e^{\frac{i \pi  (2 m+1)}{2 n}}(-1)}{1-e^{\frac{2 i \pi  (2 m+1)}{2 n}}}$$
$$= \frac{2e^{\frac{i \pi  (2 m+1)}{2 n}}}{1-e^{\frac{2 i \pi  (2 m+1)}{2 n}}}$$
$$= \frac{2}{e^{\frac{-i \pi  (2 m+1)}{2 n}}-e^{\frac{i \pi  (2 m+1)}{2 n}}}$$
$$= \frac{2}{2i\sin(\frac{-\pi  (2 m+1)}{2 n})}$$
$$= \frac{i}{\sin(\frac{\pi  (2 m+1)}{2 n})}$$

Thanks a lot, Now I get it, but there is one negative sign before the RHS, but I can see the answer is correct without it. So could it be a mistake in book print, or we are missing something here??

@Asim It's a mistake in the book, all right.

thank you so much for the help.

Yeah, I noticed the sign error too.  But my last two steps have the same sign because there are two negations (one because $1/i = -i$, and the other because $\sin$ is an odd function) which cancel out.
